# Simple Curve Fitting Implimentation in C++ (SVD Least Sqares Fit or similar)

Tags: c++, curve

I have been scouring the internet for quite some time now, trying to find a simple, intuitive, and fast way to approximate a 2nd degree polynomial using 5 data points.

I am using VC++ 2008.

I have come across many libraries, such as cminipack, cmpfit, lmfit, etc... but none of them seem very intuitive and I have had a hard time implementing the code.

Ultimately I have a set of discrete values put in a 1D array, and I am trying to find the 'virtual max point' by curve fitting the data and then finding the max point of that data at a non-integer value (where an integer value would be the highest accuracy just looking at the array).

Anyway, if someone has done something similar to this, and can point me to the package they used, and maybe a simple implementation of the package, that would be great!

I am happy to provide some test data and graphs to show you what kind of stuff I'm working with, but I feel my request is pretty straightforward. Thank you so much.

EDIT: Here is the code I wrote which works!
http://pastebin.com/tUvKmGPn

change size to change how many inputs are used

0 0
1 1
2 4
4 16
7 49

a: 1 b: 0 c: 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fitting a least-squares parabola to 5 data points? Do you require it to be of the form y = ax^2 + bx + c or do you require the ability to fit it to 'free' points (ie a rotation of a standard parabola??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to fit a standard parabola of the form

```
    y = ax^2 + bx + c
```

to your 5 data points, then all you will need is to solve a 3 x 3 matrix equation. Take a look at this example http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/lectures/lsq2.html - it works through the same problem you seem to be describing (only using more data points). If you have a basic grasp of calculus and are able to invert a 3x3 matrix (or something nicer numerically - which I am guessing you do given you refer specifically to SVD in your question title) then this example will clarify what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this method before, and I do have a general background in Linear Alg and should be able to do this, but what it seemed to be missing is some sort of minimization of the function to best fit the data, from what I understand, this method will give 1 result for any set of points, but who is to say this result is the best fit?

Comment: @user1396977 Linear least-squares is UNIQUE - the minimisation step comes from the partial derivatives w.r.t your approximation parameters (a,b,c) and setting them to zero. The final set of equations you solve is used to obtain the parameters. Do not worry - this equation gives you THE least-squares polynomial of degree 2 to your data. It is unique. The method will only fail if you do not have distinct x values in your data.

Comment: Another point that I need to address with this fitting, is that i need a fast algorithm since my program is dependent on running this many tens of thousands of times. I def see this is a general way to do it, but other methods like SVD or levmar are optimized, are they not?

Comment: levmar is for NONLINEAR problems which this is not. SVD is not a trivial algorithm. For something this small with just degree 2 polynomial fit to 5 points I would think that a closed form approach like this is sufficient. For more general problems (more data points and higher degree polynomials) then I would recommend finding a QR factorisation method. If you are doing a lot of this you would be best served getting a grasp of the theory involved - a introductory text on numerical analysis would be a good starting place. If you have linear algebra already this is a good start.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.
I will write the code to use this method, and luckily C++ has some good linear algebra libraries if I remember correctly.

Comment: It is not nice numerically to do it but you can calculate the 3x3 inverse by hand. If you can get hold of it try this book - its a good introduction and teaches you about numerical stability also http://www-maths.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~gmp/gmptheo.html

Comment: thanks so much, here is the code I wrote and it works great.
I did as you suggested, and solved the inverse on my own, and hard coded it into my program. Then some tricky for loops to do some matrix multiplication, and now I have a least square approximation for quadratic functions!

http://pastebin.com/tUvKmGPn

0 0
1 1
2 4
4 16
7 49

a: 1 b: 0 c: 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) to do the symbolic matrix algebra for you. It was a godsend in robotics courses I took.

Comment: @user1396977 Glad it is working. Just a final word of advice - if you can find some general linear algebra libraries it is better to use them, but if not it is safer to map your x values to the range [-1,1] or [0,1] for greater numerical stability. Or if you are feeling brave look up chebyshev polynomials and use those as a polynomial basis.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I do not understand what you are implying exactly and how it would be more stable. Are you saying my code as of right now, could be crashed with certain parameters for the [x,y] values?

Comment: @user1396977 no it wont crash, although you should be checking for the matrix to be singular. I mean NUMERICAL stability - using chebyshev polynomial basis is more stable numerically than polynomial. For your 3 x 3 case things should be fine, but if you scale up to more points and higher degrees I would suggest using a linear algebra library. It is common to map the data (abscissa = x values) to [0,1] or [-1,1] to improve numerical stability. If a routine is not stable numerically, you can get slight errors in your approximation parameters.

Comment: This is a good example of poor numerical stability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Well I do not ever plan on going over 5 points, so I will prolly just stick to this, but I will keep that in mind for the future. Thank you, your knowledge has helped me greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Wikipedia page on Poynomial Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression)