# How to re-integrate the discrete points generated by mouse movement in the touch screen

Tags: c++, algorithm, curve-fitting

[image: Get the points whit Touch event]

As we can see， there are some points in the upper part of the letter C that are not on the arc,  Is there an algorithm  to recalculate these points on the arc to fit into a smooth curve. Yes,I know math is hard, so I hope some body can help me.

Comment: what did you try? keywords "curve fitting", "polynomial fitting", existing article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233404/simple-curve-fitting-implimentation-in-c-svd-least-sqares-fit-or-similar

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to *filter* your data, i.e. remove points that don't lie on the curve, or do you want to *smoothen* your data, i.e. move outliers closer to the curve?

Comment: Remove points that don't lie on the curve, that is my first point